# Why backticks command exit first while testing?

Tags: ruby, minitest

If I open pry and run

```
o = `npm outdated`
```

I get the behavior that I expect, it blocks everything until the `npm` command return and store the output.

The same code, in a test:

```
def get_outdated
 o = `npm outdated`
end

def test_get_outdated
 assert_equal(true, get_outdated().length > 1)
end
```

Fail because if I print the `o` before return it is empty, and I noticed that the test runs way faster so it is impossible that it waits until the command finishes.

Printing the exit code of the process it show no errors.

```
puts $?.success? #=> true
```

Comment: Ruby `backtick` is method is synchronous  i.e. it waits for the command it calls to return. You could replace your command with `echo foo` and see that it works. I guess the issue comes from your `npm`. try `npm set progress=false` or print the `get_outdated` result in your test for deeper inspection.

Comment: There are a lot of things that might be wrong, few of which we can debug without more information. That said, you might want to check for different environment variables, esp. the current working directory and the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty likely that your environment is different in testing than in pry. One thing you could check is if you have any packages installed at all:

```
puts `npm ls`
```

With no packages installed or if all of your packages are updated, `npm outdated` returns immediately with no output and a successful return code. That would be consistent with the behavior you are observing.

You could also try running `npm config ls -l` to verify your configuration is the same both ways you are running the command.